# Android - Display progress dialog right after button is clicked

Tags: android, progressdialog

I am doing lazy loading and almost done with it. But would like to implement a progress dialog with it because it takes about 10seconds between starting the activity and finishing displaying the contents. Once I click on a button to start, it stays at the current page(Main.java) for about 4 second before moving to the next page(Activity.java). Then it takes about 2-4 seconds to display contents.

Tried the examples available here and on the net but they aren't working well (able to display the dialog but unable to do a proper dismiss after content are all downloaded).

Question is, how can I implement a progress indicator immediately once the user clicks on the button?

Activity.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);        

    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);           
    adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, mStrings, dStrings );
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
}    

private String[] mStrings = {};
private String[] dStrings = {};

public Activity()
{
    String imageC = "";
    String textC = "";

    try {
        // Get the URL from text box and make the URL object

        URL url = new URL(targetURL);

        // Make the connection
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
         new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        String line = reader.readLine();
        Pattern sChar = Pattern.compile("&.*?;");
        Matcher msChar = sChar.matcher(line);
        while (msChar.find()) line = msChar.replaceAll("");

        while (line != null) {

            if(line.contains("../../"))
            {

                int startIndex = line.indexOf("../../") + 6;
                int endIndex = line.indexOf(">", startIndex + 1);
                String abc = "http://www.petschannel.com/";
                String imageSrc = line.substring(startIndex,endIndex);
                //complete full url
                String xyz = abc +imageSrc;
                xyz = xyz.substring(0,xyz.indexOf('"'));
                xyz = xyz +";";
                imageC += xyz;                  
                mStrings = imageC.split(";");
                line = reader.readLine();
            }

            if(line.contains("../../") == false)
            {
                line = reader.readLine();
            }

            if (line.contains("Gnametag"))
            {
                int startIndex = line.indexOf("Gnametag") + 10;
                int endIndex = line.indexOf("<", startIndex + 1);
                String gname = line.substring(startIndex,endIndex);
                textC += "Name: "+gname+ "\n";
            }               

            if (line.contains("Last Update"))
            {
                reader.close();
            }                               
        }           

        // Close the reader
        reader.close();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();           
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you are doing your network call on the main thread, this is a classic no-no for performance reasons, amongst others.  Never do any operation that may  be time consuming on the main (ui) thread.

I would suggest using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), which ensures in this case, that your network call would be done in a worker thread, and the result posted back to the main thread.

AsyncTask has methods to manage progress bars, `onProgressUpdate` and `publishProgress` that will help you solve your stated problem.  There are many good articles about this, [here is one](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html).

Comment: What is suggested for my case then? I tried creating a private String[]. Then changed method to void. But it's not running the method. And what do I need to do by using AsyncTask? Call my method in it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
final ProgressDialog myDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Title", "Message");

Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        /* Your code goes here */
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            myDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}

thread.start();
```